# How to prevent removing white spaces while writing serialized json

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write serialized json data into the file. I'm using `application/octet-stream` but when I run the code, it removes all white spaces (even within strings). How do I avoid from this stuation?

```
const link = document.createElement("a")
link.download = "file.json"
link.href = "data:application/octet-stream," + content
link.click()
```

Comment: I asked from phone so I'll appriciate if someone edit the question

Comment: Whitespaces are not significant. Why do you care?

Comment: You want to print it out? Like on paper? Well, there's always `<pre>`

Comment: It also removes inline spaces and makes sentences unreadable

Comment: I mean I wanna make downloadable content for client

Comment: How do you get this `content`?

Comment: please share content as well to debug

Comment: If you want to make JSON human-readable you'll need to parse it and replace line-breaks etc. with actual HTML markup.

Comment: content contains kind of user data like "name":"Morgan Freeman". But in downloaded file it shows "MorganFreeman" it removes inline white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, to use encodeURI to preserve white spaces

```js
var content = `Morgan Freeman`
const link = document.createElement("a")
link.download = "file.json"
link.href = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURI(content)
link.click()
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NVwgKg?editors=1010

encodeURI adds the escape sequences to the spaces and there by preserves spaces

Replaces space with %20 i.e Morgan%20Freeman

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: That works ! Thank you mate but may I ask a question. How encodeURL makes a different ?

Comment: @TeomanTıngır, Glad it works, updated my post with reference link

Comment: @TeomanTıngır Because a space isn't a valid character in a URI, and the browser is "kind" enough to remove it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can encode `content` as base64, like

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,eyJhIiA6ICJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZCJ9
                             ^-----^ Notice this
```

which decodes to `{"a" : "hello world"}` preserving spaces.